# Stable power for LED from 5.5 to 7.5V AC

Tags: led, dc, ac, rectifier

About a year ago I posed the question "Making 12V DC from 6V AC".  Since the conversion from AC was going to be problematic (for me), I tackled the tail/brake light first, because working with the 6V DC side of the wiring circuit was much easier for me to grasp.  Now I'm ready to create an LED headlight.  The source is the AC leg of my Honda's generator which produces 5.5V AC at idle and about 7.5V AC at high rpm.  Instead of my original desire to double the 6V to 12V, I'd like to simply rectify the AC to DC and build an LED headlight from there.

I believe that a full bridge rectifier with a capacitor is my best option for producing clean DC for the LEDs, but I think I'll also need a regulator.  Would I regulate before or after I rectify?  I'm confident that I can develop the proper LED array, once I decide on which LEDs I'll use and what output of my conversion yields.  I didn't have to figure all that out for the tail light, since it pulled from the 6V battery.

Thanks for the assistance and remember, I'm just good enough to install lights and stereos.  I don't have any formal education on electricity... I just know it hurts sometimes.

Comment: You would regulate after rectification. You first rectify the AC so don't have any negative voltages. Then use an output capacitor that will *smooth* the output voltage and then clamp (with a regulator) the output below the ripple associated with the capacitor discharge. I could not find any good illustrations of each stage I speak of above so I will leave actually answering this question to someone who perhaps has access to such resources.

Comment: What DC voltage and current do you want to end up with?  This needs to be decided before a circuit can be supplied.

Comment: 5.5VAC will make about 6.5 VDC after full wave rectification & 7.5 VAC about 9 VDC+. You need to say how much headlight power you need (5W modern LED ~= 50W - 70W+ of halogen properly done). IF you wanted 1.5A at about 3.5 VDC for a single super LED and you used a linear regulator you would dissipate (5.5V-3.5V)*1.5A = 3 Watts in a heat sink at idle and at high RPM (9V-3.5V) x 1.5 =~ 8 Watts. Both can be handled with a decent heatsink. Using a switching regulator would greatly reduce heat and perhaps add complexity BUT you can cheaply buy modules on ebay that do what you want. Tell us more.

Comment: What Honda model is it? Does it have a battery. Batteryless models may need a load to hold the voltage down and Vout can go VERY high if load is removed. [Long ago: If you convert to 12V & halogens & on a back country "gravel" road miss a gear at speed as you enter a ford at about 1 am on an otherwise pitchblack night the water can be very very bright and then totally black and then splash ... wow. If a Honda 750 passes by you can probably ride 'on his shoulder' and use his headlight for the 10 miles or so to the next town where you rewire to std electrics.{NZ Shell 500 24 hour trial, 197?}

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Your second reply prompted me to go back and measure the VAC again.  This time with engine running, I unplugged the headlight and the VAC jumped immediately to 12 with numbers hitting the 40s when I conservatively revved the engine.  My 5.5 to 7.5 VAC is apparently wrong.  I didn't realize the load made such a difference.  It's a 1980 XL 185S, which means I'll have great difficulty keeping up with a 750 unless he's taking his time.

I was aiming for ten 5W 20mm Star LEDs.  They have a FV of 3.8, I believe.  I haven't purchased them yet, so I'm flexible still.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be a bridge rectifier and linear regulator, with some fairly big smoothing capacitors. The resulting voltage will be quite low though, maybe 3V. A switch mode supply will product whatever voltage you need but is much more complicated, so you might want to try and source a commercial one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a full-wave rectifier sent to a smoothing capacitor. Then you'll want a switching (for efficiency) or linear voltage regulator. After that, it's important that you drive the LED's with a constant current supply/driver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ZKL2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that current regulators may be made easily from adjustable voltage regulators. Wikipedia has a good example of that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source):
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason OP couldn't just use a current-limiting resistor in place of the current regulator?

Comment: @Funkyguy Depends on how well regulated he wants it. A resistor turns an LED's exponential voltage-current relationship into linear one. That may or may not be good enough. A current regulator turns an LED's exponential voltage-current relationship into a horizontal line. An increase in voltage doesn't change the current at all. For small LEDs, I don't think I'd have a problem with a resistor. For higher power leds I'd go with current regulation. Without more specific specifications, I can't say whether or not a resistor would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is evident from your response to my questions that the alternator voltage is very strongly load and RPM dependant and you are going to need more than a basic linear regulator to meet your need.

One "solution" is to clamp the rectified alternator output voltage with a battery. Alternators tend to become approximately constant current sources above a certain RPM level as the iron cores saturate. As a consequence you can increase available power, within limits, by increasing voltage. Long long ago I had a small Suzuki with a 6V lighting system. By using 12V halogen bulbs I could get about 2 x the original power from the alternator. Missing a gear change at speed so that the engine free revved would usually blow a 12V halogen bulb!

The easiest solution is liable to be to rectify the alternator output and charge a battery - 12V probably. Whether your bike has a battery now I know not.

Somewhat more work but potentially [[pun noted]] more useful would be to use a suitably capable buck converter to transform the available voltage down to what you need. You can get suitable devices on eg ebay at amazingly good prices. If you are interested in pursuing this approach please advise and we can discuss it further.

---

Prior notes:

5.5VAC will make about 6.5 VDC after full wave rectification & 7.5 VAC about 9 VDC+.
You need to say how much headlight power you need (5W modern LED ~= 50W - 70W+ of halogen properly done). IF you wanted 1.5A at about 3.5 VDC for a single super LED and you used a linear regulator you would dissipate (5.5V-3.5V)*1.5A = 3 Watts in a heat sink at idle and at high RPM (9V-3.5V) x 1.5 =~ 8 Watts. Both can be handled with a decent heatsink. Using a switching regulator would greatly reduce heat and perhaps add complexity BUT you can cheaply buy modules on ebay that do what you want.

What Honda model is it?
Does it have a battery. Batteryless models may need a load to hold the voltage down and Vout can go VERY high if load is removed.

You replied:

> Your second reply prompted me to go back and measure the VAC again. This time with engine running, I unplugged the headlight and the VAC jumped immediately to 12 with numbers hitting the 40s when I conservatively revved the engine. My 5.5 to 7.5 VAC is apparently wrong. I didn't realize the load made such a difference. It's a 1980 XL 185S, which means I'll have great difficulty keeping up with a 750 unless he's taking his time. I was aiming for ten 5W 20mm Star LEDs. They have a FV of 3.8, I believe. I haven't purchased them yet, so I'm flexible still.

Look at Cree XR-E and similar LEDs. Immensely capable. 5 of those would burn oncoming vehicles off the road. Almost :-). Probably 10+ x the output per Watt of a halogen bulb.
50W of XR-E would light up the night and part of the next day as well :-)

---

Long ago: If you convert to 12V & halogens & on a back country "gravel" road miss a gear at speed as you enter a ford at about 1 am on an otherwise pitchblack night the water can be very very bright and then totally black and then splash ... wow.
If a Honda 750 passes by you can probably ride 'on his shoulder' and use his headlight for the 10 miles or so to the next town where you rewire to std electrics.{NZ Shell 500 24 hour trial, 197?}
And, on a "decent" NZ back country gravel road late at night, a race kitted Suzuki 90 was probably a more pleasant proposition than a Honda 750 of the day - and possibly about as fast in most cases. At least as long as the headlight lasted :-). (Not that absolute speed counted -  finding checkpoints and arriving on time did).